# Is there a way to use torch.nn.DataParallel with CPU?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pytorch

I'm trying to change some PyTorch code so that it can run on the CPU.

The model was trained with `torch.nn.DataParallel()` so when I load the pre-trained model and try using it I must use `nn.DataParallel()` which I am currently doing like this:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0")
net = nn.DataParallel(net, device_ids=[0])
net.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
net.to(device)
```

However after I switched my torch device to cpu like this:

```
device = torch.device('cpu')
net = nn.DataParallel(net, device_ids=[0])
net.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
net.to(device)
```

I got this error:

```
File "C:\My\Program\win-py362-venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\parallel\data_parallel.py", line 156, in forward
    "them on device: {}".format(self.src_device_obj, t.device))
RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:0 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cpu
```

I'm assuming that it's still looking for CUDA because that's what `device_ids` is set to but is there a way to make it use the CPU? [This post from the PyTorch repo](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/44938) makes me think that I can but it doesn't explain how.

If not is there any other way to use a model trained with DataParallel on your CPU?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use `torch.nn.DataParallel()` it implements data parallelism at the module level.

[According to the doc:](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.DataParallel.html)

> The parallelized module must have its parameters and buffers on device_ids[0] before running this DataParallel module.

So even though you are doing `.to(torch.device('cpu'))` it is still expecting to pass the data to a GPU.

However since `DataParallel` is a container you can bypass it and get just the original module by doing this:

```
net = net.module.to(device)
```

Now it will access the original module you defined before you applied the `DataParallel` container.